# How to disable VLC output in command-line mode?

Tags: command-line, vlc, output, cvlc

When I play music on `vlc` or `cvlc` in terminal or console there is always this *(shown below)* non-stopping output that prevents me from issuing commands by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. I want to disable it, I tried to start vlc with `vlc -q` switch in quite mode but it only gets rid of **[ ]** bracket parts, the rest still remains and continues to grow.

So, how to make `vlc` completely not to show this information and still be able to execute command-line commands like `next`, `play`, `random` etc?

```
VLC media player 2.0.7 Twoflower (revision 2.0.6-54-g7dd7e4d)
[0x255e418] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sdb1 mounted on /run/media/easl/freyja for CSS authentication
libdvdread: Could not open input: Permission denied
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sdb1 for reading
libdvdread: Device /dev/sdb1 inaccessible, CSS authentication not available.
libdvdnav:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdnav:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.
libdvdnav: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
[0x24966b8] main playlist: stopping playback
TagLib: MPEG::Header::parse() -- Invalid sample rate.
TagLib: ID3v2.4 no longer supports the frame type TDAT.  It will be discarded from the tag.
TagLib: MPEG::Header::parse() -- Invalid sample rate.
TagLib: MPEG::Header::parse() -- Invalid sample rate.
TagLib: ID3v2.4 no longer supports the frame type TDAT.  It will be discarded from the tag.
TagLib: MPEG::Header::parse() -- Invalid sample rate.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get rid of the output of the libraries by piping stderr away

```
cvlc -q mymedia 2> /dev/null
```

As for the commands, I'm not sure vlc accepts commands from plain stdin, but it sounds like the rc interface might be what you're looking for.

```
cvlc -q -Irc mymedia 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: what is the difference between rc and dummy interfaces?

Comment: The dummy interface is just a placeholder for "no interface at all". So if you're telling vlc everything you want it to do through command line arguments, and don't want/need to interact with it after its started, you don't need a control interface so you use a dummy one instead.
The rc (Remote Control) interface can be used to issue commands to vlc after it has started, either from the command line or even remotely (see manual http://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces and http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html#id590986)

Comment: the command should look like this to return to bas `cvlc -q mymedia 2> /dev/null &`   .